# Android, custom component design

Tags: android, custom-component

In my application I need to have something like image below. I have experience of creating custom components and I know how to do it. However, I have no idea how to create this kind of component. Do I need to do something like when we are designing custom rating bar?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, their so many way you can achieve this.

One way i am seeing using radio group and radio button, vertical lines and text view you can easily achieve this. Put everything inside a layout of your choice and then just inflate the layout where ever you need. After that you just need to set the radio button like this `radio1.setChecked(true)`.This is a simple solution but may not a be a optimal one.

Alternatively you can create a custom view by extending view class or any of its subclass, whatever you feel suitable for your work then override its onDraw method do the entire thing manually.